# ActionbarSherlock theming crash reports

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm getting a few crash reports as below

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must use Theme.Sherlock, Theme.Sherlock.Light, Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar, or a derivative.
```

I check my manifest file and it correctly set the theme

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="XXX"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar" 
        android:name="com.XXX.myapp">
        <activity
            android:name="XXX"
            android:label="XXX"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"            
            android:launchMode="singleTop" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Does anyone know what the issue is?

When I look into ABS, it seems to fail right here

```
if (!a.hasValue(R.styleable.SherlockTheme_windowActionBar)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("You must use Theme.Sherlock, Theme.Sherlock.Light, Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar, or a derivative.");
        }
```

Comment: Nope, I updated the question with the activity part of the manifest.